# How to monitor Network traffic with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, networking, ifconfig

ifconfig -output is somewhat messy thing to look at. When I saw the nice output below with the command [(source)](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialMySQL.html), the question emerged:

> Is there some more structured way, let say
>   MySQL, to look at ifconfig or similar data?

It would be cool, if I could monitor the network traffic in databases.

```
[prompt]$ mysqladmin -h localhost -u root -p processlist

+----+------+-----------+----+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| Id | User | Host      | db | Command | Time | State | Info             |
+----+------+-----------+----+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| 15 | root | localhost |    | Query   | 0    |       | show processlist |
+----+------+-----------+----+---------+------+-------+------------------+
```

Comment: You can use Percona's Tcpdump plugin - http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-playback/plugins/tcpdump/index.html to achieve this. You can check `Bytes_received` and `Bytes_sent` MySQL status variable values as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL GUI Tools and administrator tools allow you to monitor to some extent. if you want raw packets, you can either use Ethereal or Wireshark